# Can I use single app in Actions on Google to work both in English and Japanese?

Tags: dialogflow-es, actions-on-google, google-home, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I am making an app in Actions on Google. It was working fine on English language . I need to make it work for Japanese also. But as I have read in google docs I understand that we can create same app supporting multi languages which will be shown in Dialogflow. But as per my knowledge these languages are switched with respect to the default language selected in the google home. For example, if the Home is in Japanese language it will be invoking the Japanese version. I want to know is there any method to change language by its invoke call or by asking first question about the preferred language? Please anyone give a right way to get these things done.

My app is still under testing. Not yet published.

Comment: So you're asking about an action that is started in English but then speaks Japanese?

Comment: It will detect in which language user asks for the action. Suppose i am asking google assistant to talk to some chinese action, it will automaticaly start it and if i have said it in english like talk to something something, it will start action in english. Again it will be based on languages user have added in settings section of assitant.